# Resolving systemd dependency on Amazon Linux to permit RabbitMQ install

Tags: centos, systemd, dependencies, rabbitmq

I am trying to install rabbitmq server from rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.e17.noarch.rpm on an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux. I understand that Amazon Linux evolved from CentOS and RHEL Linux, so I looked for install packages intended for those.

RMQ has an erlang dependency. I installed erlang from erlang-19.3.6-1.e17.centos.src.rpm. That install ran successfully.

The rabbitmq install from the rpm mentioned above via /bin/rpm -Uvh /local/downloads/rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.el7.noarch.rpm resulted in several dependency errors. One requires socat. The second requires systemd. That error is: systemd is needed by rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.el7.noarch

I resolved the first dependency with `yum install socat`.

I've done research but have as yet been unable to overcome that second dependency on systemd so that I can install rabbitmq in this environment. I suspect that Amazon Linux may lock me in to System V init, and may preclude me from using systemd. In which case my only option will be to abandon all the work I've done on this server and re-establish it with another operating system option - CentOS, for example.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Instead of asking if someone encountered your problem (answer: Yes, you did) it is better to just directly ask the question for which the answer would help you.

Comment: How can I resolve the rabbitMQ dependency on systemd in an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux? The rabbitMQ instance I am attempting to install is rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.e17.noarch.rpm. I have successfully installed erlang from erlang-19.3.6-1.e17.centos.src.rpm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the version of Amazon Linux you are using does not have `systemd`. I'm not sure that *any* version of Amazon Linux as of today uses `systemd`. Considering that `systemd` is a core part of an operating system, it's not something you can just install as a package and expect to work.

If you can't find the packages you need built for Amazon Linux, my recommendation is to start over with an AMI from a different OS. For example, there are [AMIs for CentOS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=16cb8b03-256e-4dde-8f34-1b0f377efe89) that you could start with instead.

I recommend switching to a new Linux distribution. On a more popular Linux distribution like CentOS or Ubuntu, you are far less likely to run into problems with missing packages as you are currently experiencing with Amazon Linux.

Comment: I agree, and after much digging decided early yesterday to scrap and rebuild this EC2 instance. I rebuilt my EC2 using an AMI described as "CentOS 7 optimized for high performance". What that means is not yet clear to me, but it seemed like an attractive option given the many - almost too many - CentOS AMIs to select from. I re-established my NiFi instance on it with success, and then did a yum install to get socat and systemd loaded. Today I repeat my erlang and then rabbitmq install attempts.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it or marking it as accepted.